# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Но это был «почтовый ящик», и он имел свои негативные стороны, захотелось новой работы, и я поступила на передовое в то время предприятие ЛНПО «Знамя труда» им. И. И. Лепсе на Петроградской.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю следующую расстановку знаков препинания. Но это был «почтовый ящик», и он имел свои негативные стороны.  Захотелось новой работы, и я поступила на передовое в то время предприятие ЛНПО «Знамя труда» им. И. И. Лепсе на Петроградской.

Comment: а что с пробелом между инициалами?

Comment: Ну, это вопрос техники набора